# Active Directory not working after hosting to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Active Directory not working after hosting to IIS 7, Waiting Your Helps.

My Code Snippets.

```
 string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ADConnection"].ToString();
            DirectorySearcher dssearch = new DirectorySearcher(connection);
            dssearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + txtusername.Text + ")";
            SearchResult sresult = dssearch.FindOne();
            DirectoryEntry dsresult = sresult.GetDirectoryEntry();
            lblfname.Text = dsresult.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
            lbllname.Text = dsresult.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
            lblemail.Text = dsresult.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
```

Comment: This page has been hosted on Development server, working fine on that machine, but when we try to access from other machine it is not working.

Comment: Please edit your Question and your code set in {code} //code {code} blocks.  I don't understand because very Complex question..

Answer (score 0):

- In the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, expand , Sites, and Default Web Site in the Connections pane. 
  Click to  select the virtual directory and click the Features View at the
  bottom of the Workspace pane to list the configurable features for
  the virtual directory.
  Double-click the Authentication feature in the
  Workspace pane to list the authentication methods that are enabled
  for the virtual directory. Click to select the authentication method
  that you would like to enable or disable and click either Disable or
  Enable in the Actions pane of the IIS Manager